# Number theory to find the nth value of an infinite set of numbers satisfying a condition

Tags: number-theory

What is the $n$th value of $x$ such that $15^x \equiv x\mod 1000$ ?

I am not aware of any theorems that would help me simplify this further, so how would you solve it?

Before finding a universal solution, I would first want to solve for $n = 2018$.

Comment: what is that infinite set ?

Comment: An infinite set is a set with infinite length and having an infinite number of values. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_set)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
&15^x \equiv x\;(\text{mod}\;1000)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&x \equiv 1\;(\text{mod}\;2)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&15^{x-1} \equiv 1\;(\text{mod}\;8)&&\text{[since odd squares are congruent to $1,\;$mod $8$]}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&15^x \equiv -1\;(\text{mod}\;8)
&&\text{[since $15 \equiv -1\;(\text{mod}\;8)$]}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&x \equiv -1\;(\text{mod}\;8)&&\text{[since $8{\mid}1000$]}\\[10pt]
\text{Also}\;\;&15^x \equiv x\;(\text{mod}\;1000)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&x \equiv 0\;(\text{mod}\;5)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&15^x \equiv 0\;(\text{mod}\;125)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&x \equiv 0\;(\text{mod}\;125)&&\text{[since $125{\mid}1000$]}\\[10pt]
\end{align*}
By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, the congruences
\begin{align*}
&
\begin{cases}
x \equiv -1 \;(\text{mod}\;8)\\
x \equiv 0 \;(\text{mod}\;125)\\
\end{cases}
\\[4pt]
&\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!
\implies\;x \equiv 375\;(\text{mod}\;1000)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
So $x \equiv 375\;(\text{mod}\;1000)$ is a necessary condition.

We'll show it's also sufficient.

Thus, suppose $x$ is a positive integer such that $x \equiv 375\;(\text{mod}\;1000)$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&15^{x-1} \equiv 1\;(\text{mod}\;8)&&\text{[since $x-1$ is even]}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&15^x \equiv -1\;(\text{mod}\;8)
&&\text{[since $15 \equiv -1\;(\text{mod}\;8)$]}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&15^x \equiv x\;(\text{mod}\;8)
&&\text{[
$x \equiv 375\;(\text{mod}\;1000) \implies x \equiv -1\;(\text{mod}\;8)$
]}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&8\,{\mid}\,(15^x  - x)\\[10pt]
\text{Also}\;\;&125|15^x\;\text{and}\;125|x\\[4pt]
\implies\;&125|(15^x-x)\\[10pt]
\text{Hence}\;\;&1000|15^x-x&&\text{[since $15^x-x$ is a multiple of both $8$ and $125$]}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&15^x-x\equiv 0\;(\text{mod}\;1000)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&15^x\equiv x\;(\text{mod}\;1000)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
It follows that the $n$-th solution is given by $x = 375+(n-1)1000$.

Answer (score 2):

For $x\ge3, x=y+3$

$$y+3\equiv5^y3^{y+3}\pmod8\equiv(-3)^y3^{y+3}\equiv(-1)^y9^{y+1}3$$

$$\iff3y+9\equiv(-1)^y\pmod8\iff3y+1\equiv(-1)^y$$

If $y$ is even $=2z,$(say)
 $$6z+1\equiv1\mod8\iff3z\equiv0\pmod4\iff z\equiv0\pmod4$$

$z=4n$(say)

$x=y+3=2z+3=2(4n)+3$

What if $y$ is odd $=2z+1$(say)?

Comment: Wow, that is a creative solution to the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Note that since $15$ is not invertible $\pmod{1000}$, any solution to your equation is a positive integer. Therefore, the set of solutions is an increasing sequence of natural numbers.

Next, for $n \geq 3$ we have
$$15^n \equiv 0 \pmod{125} \\
15^n \equiv (-1)^n \pmod{8}$$

This means that, starting with $x=3$ the LHS is a periodic sequence, which repeats after two steps. The RHS repeats after 1000 steps.

From here it is easy to deduce for which $x \geq 3$ you do get equality, which gives you a closed formula for the sequence you seek.